# How can I hide the minimum value on the Y-axis of an Excel line chart without covering with a white shape?

Tags: excel, formatting, ms-office, hide, linechart

How can I hide the minimum value on the Y-axis of an Excel line chart without covering with a white shape?

I've managed to find examples of how to hide the value if it's zero:

[i.e. specify the custom formatting code as #,##0;-#,##0;;](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/12/14/how-to-hide-0-in-chart-axis/)

However, how do I hide different values such as 90 in the screen shot?

[How do I hide the value in the circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKJAr.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it is not possible to remove a single specific value through custom formatting.

With a [custom number format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4) you can specify 4 different schemata, seperated by ";":

- one for positive numbers (#,##0)
- one for negative numbers (#,##0)
- one for zero ()
- one for text ()

The custom format `#,##0;-#,##0;;` works for axis values of 0, because it formats zeroes differently than positive and negative numbers. You cannot, however, format one specific positive number differently than all other positive numbers on the axis.